# Unable to locate package while installing any software

Tags: apt

Whenever I try to install any application with this code

```
$ sudo apt-get install <package>
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package vlc
```

I followed intructions like installing universe, multiverse... repositories. And when I try to update it with this code

```
sudo apt-get update
```

it gives errors like

```
$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for palash: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for palash: 
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic InRelease                                
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic Release.gpg                              
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic Release
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic InRelease
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic/main Sources
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic/main amd64 Packages      
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates InRelease     
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic/main i386 Packages
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports InRelease   
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-security InRelease
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic Release.gpg
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates Release.gpg
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports Release.gpg
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-security Release.gpg
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic Release
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates Release
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic/main Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports Release
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-security Release
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/main Sources    
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/restricted Sources
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/universe Sources     
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/multiverse Sources   
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/main amd64 Packages  
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/restricted amd64 Packages
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/universe amd64 Packages
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/multiverse amd64 Packages
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/main i386 Packages   
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/restricted i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/universe i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/multiverse i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/main Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/main Translation-en
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/multiverse Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/multiverse Translation-en
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/restricted Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/restricted Translation-en
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/universe Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/universe Translation-en
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/main Sources 
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/restricted Sources
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/universe Sources
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/multiverse Sources
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/main amd64 Packages
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/universe amd64 Packages
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/main i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/restricted i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/universe i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/main Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/main Translation-en
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/multiverse Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/multiverse Translation-en
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/restricted Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/restricted Translation-en
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/universe Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/universe Translation-en
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/main Sources
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/restricted Sources
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/universe Sources
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/multiverse Sources
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/main amd64 Packages
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/universe amd64 Packages
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/main i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/restricted i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/universe i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/main Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/main Translation-en
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/multiverse Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/multiverse Translation-en
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/restricted Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/restricted Translation-en
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/universe Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/universe Translation-en
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-security/main Sources
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-security/restricted Sources
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-security/universe Sources
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-security/multiverse Sources
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-security/main amd64 Packages
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-security/restricted amd64 Packages
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-security/universe amd64 Packages
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-security/main i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-security/restricted i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-security/universe i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-security/multiverse i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-security/main Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-security/main Translation-en
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-security/multiverse Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-security/multiverse Translation-en
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-security/restricted Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-security/restricted Translation-en
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-security/universe Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-security/universe Translation-en
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/source/Sources  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/restricted/source/Sources  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/universe/source/Sources  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/multiverse/source/Sources  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/universe/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/i18n/Translation-en_US  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_US  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/restricted/i18n/Translation-en_US  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/restricted/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/universe/i18n/Translation-en_US  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/universe/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/main/source/Sources  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/restricted/source/Sources  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/universe/source/Sources  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/multiverse/source/Sources  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/main/i18n/Translation-en_US  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/main/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_US  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/restricted/i18n/Translation-en_US  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/restricted/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/universe/i18n/Translation-en_US  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/universe/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/main/source/Sources  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/restricted/source/Sources  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/universe/source/Sources  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/multiverse/source/Sources  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/main/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/universe/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/main/i18n/Translation-en_US  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/main/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_US  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/restricted/i18n/Translation-en_US  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/restricted/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/universe/i18n/Translation-en_US  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/universe/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/main/source/Sources  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/restricted/source/Sources  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/universe/source/Sources  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/multiverse/source/Sources  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/main/i18n/Translation-en_US  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/main/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_US  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/restricted/i18n/Translation-en_US  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/restricted/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/universe/i18n/Translation-en_US  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/universe/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

what can I do now?

Comment: Post the errors from `apt-get update`.

Comment: Could you please update your question with the output from ' sudo apt-get update' ?

Comment: @karel did i do it right? 'palash@palash-Inspiron-3420:~$ sudo sed -i -re 's/([a-z]{2}\.)?archive.ubuntu.com|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
[sudo] password for palash: 
palash@palash-Inspiron-3420:~$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
palash@palash-Inspiron-3420:~$ '

Comment: First you need to unlock `/var/lib/dpkg/` to continue - [Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) is another process using it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process) Start by trying Bruno Pereira's answer.

Comment: @karel the link you provided worked

Answer (score 2):

Utopic Unicorn reached its End of Life on July 23, 2015

You need a new install.

It's not an LTS (Long Term Support) 14.04 was an LTS which is still alive , and 16.04 is an LTS.